# Twisted UDP Server multiple Clients

Tags: python, sockets, udp, twisted, datagram

Hi I am trying to implement a basic server client using twisted. My server is a pc and clients are small embedded devices which will be communicating over UDP via a wifi. Here is a very small implementation I did using examples

```
from twisted.internet.protocol import DatagramProtocol
from twisted.internet import protocol, reactor
import time
from socket import SOL_SOCKET, SO_BROADCAST

class Echo(protocol.DatagramProtocol):
   def datagramReceived(self, data, (host, port)):
       while(1):
          self.transport.write(data, (host, port))
          ##Recieve Some thing here on the current ip
          ##Perform some task have to send and recieve couple of
          ##times
          time.sleep(3)

   def main():

       reactor.listenUDP(8000, Echo())
       reactor.run()
       print 'Reactor running\n'
       #protocol.startProtocol()
       while(1):
          command_input = input("Enter your Command ")
          if command_input == exit:
              print 'Exiting'
              exit()

if __name__ == '__main__':
   main()
```

I will receive a packet from a client then I will have to send some data back, and then again client will send some data and this would keep on for some while. Is there any way I can do this in datagramRecieved() function and at same time service other clients as well. In this implementation once datagramRecieved() function is called I cant recieve anything else until it returns. There is a concept of factories(used in tcp i think) can it be implemented here.

Answer (score 0):

To get the effect here where you send a packet every 3 seconds, you want to use [`LoopingCall`](https://twistedmatrix.com/documents/15.4.0/api/twisted.internet.task.LoopingCall.html).  In fact, if you `sleep` like in your example, depending on the size of various buffers, you might not even send those packets at all until you get back to the reactor; writes are an event just like reads.

An example of how that might work:

```
from twisted.internet import protocol, task
class Echo(protocol.DatagramProtocol):
   def datagramReceived(self, data, (host, port)):
       def reply():
           self.transport.write(data, (host, port))
       task.LoopingCall(reply).start(3.0)
```